# Свинний чи свинячий?

Tags: вибір-слова, прикметники

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/svynjachyj) зафіксовано лише слово "свинячий":

> **СВИНЯ́ЧИЙ**, а, е. Прикм. до свиня 1.

У [Словнику русинської мови](http://slovo.sochka.com/index.php?letter=ch) подають інший варіант:

> ШОВДАРЬ - **свинний** окорок.

Використання слова "свинний" бачу й у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0):

> Зі **свинної** корейки відрізають шийну частину між четвертим і п'ятим ребрами.

А також [тут](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/41610-podrib.html), [тут](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/prykmetnyky) та ін.

Отож як правильно: свинячий чи свинний? Адже навіть і в м’ясних магазинах пишуть по-різному.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У своєму [блозі](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/forum/story/2009/11/091105_ponomariv_blog_it.shtml) професор Пономарів пише:

> Насправді треба казати "свинячий грип", оскільки прикметника "свинний" немає в українській мові. Це непотрібна калька з російської мови.

Отже, посилаючись на авторитетного мовознавця, робимо висновок, що правильно - *"свинячий"* і ніяк інакше, бо "свинний" - калька.

Comment: Додам, що свинний ще й відсутнє в багатьох словниках, наприклад: [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/), [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).

Comment: Думаю не варто послуговуватися логікою: ''Аби не так, як в москалів''. Є правила словотворення + рекомендації використовувати найкоротші варіанти слова. "Свин" - корінь, "н" - суфікс, "ий" - закінчення. Що саме з вище переліченого є калькою? Ми ж не говоримо "рибнячий жир" або "твариняча шкура". Максимум тут можна говорити про мовну традицію, але варто уникати тверджень "неправильно".

Comment: Muffin, То по вашому правильно писати куринне, телинне, козинне м'ясо? І не шкура, а шкіра і також правильно писати свиняча шкіра.

Comment: @Олександр, мені здається, Ви неуважно прочитали, [muffin (навпаки) стверджує, що правильно _свинячий_, а не _свинний_](/a/4732). Можливо, Ви мали на увазі [коментар](/q/4729#comment7535_4732) Юрія Гладьо?

Comment: @Олександр, до речі, є слово [шкіра](http://sum.in.ua/s/shkira) і є слово [шкура](http://sum.in.ua/s/shkura) — у деяких контекстах вони обидва застосовні.

Answer (score 1):

Нема якогось правила, яке б вказувало, як творити такі прикметники. Тому є *свинячий* [переважна форма], але є і *свинний*. Є *козячий*, *козиний* і навіть *козій*. Тож не варто аж так цим перейматися. Тре змиритися з хаосом. *Кіт* — *котячий*, *кит* — *китовий*, а *тюлень* — *тюленячий* і *тюленевий*. І не паритися. Є *звіриний* і *звірячий*. Ніщо не заважає утворити *тваринний* і *тваринячий*. У першій парі переважатиме ужиток другого, а в другій — першого. І по всьому